# Run WPF application on ASP.NET using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a project in WPF application now I wish to run my WPF application which is developed in Visual Studio 2012 in ASP.NET.

Kindly tell me how can I run it on ASP.NET? If it is not possible then tell me alternative method

Comment: WPF is **not** ASP.NET - those technologies are **totally separate**. You cannot run a WPF application *on* ASP.NET - if would have to completely rewrite your WPF application to use an ASP.NET web frontend (instead of the WPF frontend) ......

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run WPF on the web : you can do it using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  altho it isn't a good way to deploy a web application in the general case. In the book [WPF Unleashed](http://www.adamnathan.net/wpf/) Adam Neithan offers more information on the topic.

Comment: But i have came to know that wpf can be linked with silverlight??